# PyGObject drag and drop reorder widgets

Tags: python-3.x, drag-and-drop, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm trying to implement DND in Gtk3 with Python, but so far I only managed to catch a `drag-begin` signal. Here's the code:

```
class MyWidget(Gtk.EventBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TrackBox, self).__init__()

        self.drag_source_set(Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON1_MASK, [], Gdk.DragAction.MOVE)
        self.connect('drag-begin', self._sig_drag_begin)
        self.connect('drag-data-get', self._sig_drag_data_get)

        self.drag_dest_set(Gtk.DestDefaults.HIGHLIGHT | Gtk.DestDefaults.DROP | Gtk.DestDefaults.MOTION, [Gtk.TargetEntry.new('GTK_MYWIDGET', Gtk.TargetFlags.SAME_APP, 0)], Gdk.DragAction.MOVE)
        self.connect('drag-drop', self._sig_drag_drop)
        self.connect('drag-data-received', self._sig_drag_data_received)

    def _sig_drag_begin(self, widget, context):
        print("drag begin")
        print(self, widget, context)

    def _sig_drag_data_get(self, widget, context, selection, info, timestamp):
        print("drag data get")
        print(self, widget, context, selection, info, timestamp)

    def _sig_drag_drop(self, widget, context, x, y, timestamp):
        print('drag-drop')
        print(self, widget, context, x, y, timestamp)

    def _sig_drag_data_received(self, widget, context, x, y, selection, info, timestamp):
        print('drag-data-received')
        print(self, widget, context, x, y, selection, info, timestamp)
```

I got the output from `_sig_drag_begin`, but nothing else. The goal would be to be able to reorder these `Gtk.EventBox`-es inside a `Gtk.Box` with a somewhat similar end result as we can get with a reorderable `Gtk.TreeView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution in case anyone has the same question:

```
class TrackBox(Gtk.EventBox):
    def __init__(self, title, artist, id, year, length, album):
        super(TrackBox, self).__init__()
        
        # do your stuff here

        # Looks like this one is needed
        targs = [Gtk.TargetEntry.new("dummy", Gtk.TargetFlags.SAME_APP, 1)]

        self.drag_source_set(Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON1_MASK, targs, Gdk.DragAction.MOVE)

        self.drag_dest_set(Gtk.DestDefaults.HIGHLIGHT | Gtk.DestDefaults.DROP | Gtk.DestDefaults.MOTION, targs, Gdk.DragAction.MOVE)
        self.connect('drag-drop', self._sig_drag_drop)
        self.connect('drag-end', self._sig_drag_end)

    def _sig_drag_drop(self, widget, *_):
        # Here you get the name of the target
        print('drag-drop: get target name')
        print(widget.get_name())

    def _sig_drag_end(self, widget, _):
        # And here you get the name of the source
        # also you should write moving related code here
        print('drag-end: actually move and get source name')
        print(widget.get_name())
```

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeU4L0p1DgI) video explains everything in detail.